# SSH.NET based colored terminal emulator

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, terminal, ssh.net

I'm using SSH.NET to create my terminal application for UWP.

For now, I've been able to send/receive data with the library, but I would like to do something like the PuTTY application, that shows the text with different colors, or even being able to edit files with the Linux `vi` editor.

Is there a way to get color / position information with this library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When implementing a [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), you primarily have to process [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) sent by the server.

There's no support for that in SSH.NET or .NET Framework.

Implementing it on your own is a huge task. PuTTY implementation of the terminal emulation, [`terminal.c`](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=blob;f=terminal/terminal.c), has almost 8000 lines of code. And that's only a processing part, a drawing is separate.

Quick google search for *"c# terminal emulation"* results in:
https://github.com/munificent/malison-dotnet
(though I have no experience with this library)

---

The only part of this on SSH.NET side, is to request terminal emulation by using an overload of `SshClient.CreateShell` that takes `terminalName` argument (and its companions).