# ShellStream output contains unknown characters

Tags: vb.net, ssh, streamreader, ssh.net

I am using Ssh.Net and a `StreamReader` on its `ShellStream` to read output from an ssh console. If you are familiar with console output, you surely know about typically table formatted data. Such as:

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2     COLUMN3

value1      value2      value3

value4      value5      value6

value7      value8      value9
```

I am also reading the output directly via an `SshCommand` object and I dont have any formatting errors there. However when I am using StreamReader I get cryptic characters such as `[m[1mX[m`. The X is a single character, normally surrounded by spaces. This happens only next to single characters surrounded by multiple spaces. I also have this issue when characters are surrounded by brackets which results in something like `[9999` or `[6n`

I will parse the result anyway, so I don't mind the characters, but I need to know wether they actually mean something and if they are consistent. If it is neither of that, I would be nice if you could tell me how I can fix this issue.

If it matters, I am connected to a MikroTik Router and I run the command `certificate print detail without-paging`. This error occurs in the header and I am using this code to output acquire a result and output the stream:

```
Dim response As String = ""
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(shellStream)
Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(shellStream)

writer.WriteLine(cmd)
writer.Flush()

Thread.Sleep(500)

Dim line As String = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To 150

    response += line
    line = reader.ReadLine
    response += vbCrLf

Next

Console.WriteLine(response)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60318258/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks a lot man, couldn't find it online because search engines ignore the bracket even with qutation marks around them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are ANSI Escape Sequences - namely (replace X with correpsonding number):

[Xm - Text graphics mode (color, thickness, etc.)

[XB - Cursor down by X

[Xn - Probably new line

For more information look [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AANSI_escape_code) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

If it is of any interest: In my case I can replace every [Xm sequence because I am not using any of the given text formatting